# Newtonsoft json and graph api

Tags: json, facebook, api, graph, json.net

i use Newtonsoft json to Deserialize facebook graph api response.

for example when i parse user posts that the response is like:

```
data": [
    {
      "story": "",
      "created_time": "",
      "id": ""
    }]
```

i have created a class like:

```
 public class FacebookPost
    {
        public string created_time { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string story { get; set; }
    }
```

and the Newtonsoft appends the values directly in the class and i can use them.

my problem is when i am trying to parse comments when the api response is like:

```
"data": [
    {
      "created_time": "",
      "from": {
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
      },
      "message": "",
      "id": ""
    }]
```

there for example the name and id is inside the **from** section,
how do i have to structure the classes in order to can take values for `from.name` and `from.id`?

thank you very much 
---------------------------- new add ------
 i use the following classes :

```
 public class FacebookCommentsResults
    {
        public PostComments[] data { get; set; }        
        public FacebookPagingInfo Paging { get; set; }
    }


public class PostComments
    {
        public string created_time { get; set; }
        public From from { get; set; }
    }

public class From
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

the line  var created_time = comment.created_time; WORKS FINE! 
the next line  var name = comment.name; GIVES ERROR --> Reactions.PostComments' does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'Reactions.PostComments' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

when the response is

```
"data": [
    {
      "created_time": "",
      "from": {
        "name": "",
        "id": ""
      },
      "message": "",
      "id": ""
    }]
```

Now the json schema is changed, so we have to change our Classes. Reason is `from` is an another object in our main json, so we need the below classes to access `from.id` and `from.name`

```
public class From
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class FacebookPost
{
    public string created_time { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

### Edit

> the line var created_time = comment.created_time; WORKS FINE! the next
>   line var name = comment.name; GIVES ERROR --> Reactions.PostComments'
>   does not contain a definition for 'name' and no extension method
>   'name' accepting a first argument of type 'Reactions.PostComments'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

`from` is an object and in that object `name` is an attribute, so you cannot access it by giving `comment.name`. First you need to take the `from` object from `comment` and then you can retrieve the name attribute.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, i will add all the code to see what it returns

Comment: i added new code to the bottom of the post with the exact classes that i use and the error i get, if you have any idea please help, thanks!!!

Comment: @TeO - `from` is an object in `comment` and `name` is an attribute in `from` object. Retrieve `from` object first and then retrieve `name` attribute.